# Jquery Trigger only the main class or The sub inside it

Tags: jquery

I have a list that looks like this

```
 <li class="myList" id="01">01 - Animals; live

  <ul class="sub">
    <li class="myList2" id="0101">0101 - Horses </li>
    <li class="myList2" id="0102">0102 - Bovine animals</li>
  </ul>

 </li>
```

When I trigger click even for **myList2** myList triggers first, so the event triggers two times.

I need to trigger only MyList if the user click myList and MyList2 if the user clicks MyList2 li's.

I tried .one instead of .on it worked but I was not able to trigger click event again.

Comment: Where is your `jquery` code, what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `e.stopPropagation();` so that the event of the parent will not execute on the child.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myList").click(function() {
    alert("alert myList");
  });

  $(".myList2").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); /* Add this on Child event */
    alert("alert myList2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="myList" id="01">01 - Animals; live
  <ul class="sub">
    <li class="myList2" id="0101">0101 - Horses </li>
    <li class="myList2" id="0102">0102 - Bovine animals</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: That's work. Thank you so much. Unfortunately I cant give you a thumbs up because I'm new here. Any ways when I can I will give u a thumbs up.

Comment: Great to hear. Just accept my answer by click the check near the thumbs up/down btn  :)